# Can't remove inline event handler in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, events, google-chrome-extension

I want to delete an event handler form a form that contains an inline definition of onsubmit.

```
<form id="loginForm" onsubmit="return performTask(this);">
```

I have already try :

```
$("#loginForm").off("submit")
$("#loginForm").unbind("submit")
$("#loginForm").die("submit")
$("#loginForm").removeAttr("onsubmit")
$("#loginForm").removeProp("onsubmit")
$("#loginForm").attr("onsubmit", "")
$("#loginForm").prop("onsubmit, "")
$("#loginForm")[0].onsubmit = null
$("#loginForm")[0].onsubmit = undefined
$("#loginForm")[0].onSubmit = null
$("#loginForm")[0].onSubmit = undefined
```

And nothing works !

I add my own event listener usin jquery method on() but it is never called. It apear that the old event listener is executed before mine... It does the same thing with onClick event on button.

I have to explicit that I'm in a chrome extension and more precisely in a Content Script injected in a page.

So the question is, is there any way to purge event handlers ? Or much better is there any way to add an event listener that will be call before the inline handler ?

EDIT : After lot of ugly code, I have find a way to do what I want... I do a copy of the form, delete the inline envent handler, replace in the dom the old form by mine and then create my event handler. It's ugly but it works ... If anyone can explain why I can't do this other way ...

Comment: Is it possible the event handler is on a parent element? `<body>` maybe? The `onSubmit` event does bubble.

Comment: Nope I have put the line of the form in my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) problem. Chrome extensions run is a separate context from the page; while access to the DOM is shared, **inline event listeners are isolated**.

Quote from the documentation, emphasis mine:

> It's worth noting what happens with JavaScript objects that are shared by the page and the extension - for example, the `window.onload` event. Each isolated world sees its own version of the object. **Assigning to the object affects your independent copy of the object.** For example, both the page and extension can assign to `window.onload`, but neither one can read the other's event handler. The event handlers are called in the order in which they were assigned.

So, to override a page-level listener, you need to inject your overriding code into the page context itself. This is possible; see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/934239) for details, and here's an example:

```
var actualCode = "document.getElementById('loginForm').onsubmit = null;";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

This adds a `<script>` element to the page, which then executes in the page's own context.

Comment: Thank you ! I haved the idea of doing some thing like this :-) It's an other POC that isolated world can't really be donne with javascript when you share DOM. A huge security fail I think...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

It will stop the propagation of the event.

Comment: Already tried but not working. Like I said my event seems to be called after the inline one.

Answer (score -1):

I actually don't know the object whose 'onSubmit' event is being processed here, so using pseudo logic here:

1. Identify the object whose event is being processed - say obj.
2. Identify it's registered events - console.log(obj._events); - say it returns submit [ Function ]
3. Purge the call back: obj._events.submit = null;
4. Register your handler.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already try to purge the submit event handler like I said it in the question. It doesn't work